# Will the initialization list always be processed before the constructor code?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

Will the initialization list always be processed before the constructor code?

In other words, will the following code always print `<unknown>`, and the constructed class will have "known" as value for `source_` (if the global variable `something` is `true`)?

```
class Foo {
  std::string source_;
public:
  Foo() : source_("<unknown>") {
    std::cout << source_ << std::endl;
    if(something){
      source_ = "known";
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, it will, as per `C++11: 12.6.2 /10` (same section in `C++14`, `15.6.2 /13` in `C++17`):

---

In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following order (my bold):

- First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class (1.8), virtual base classes are initialized in the order they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed acyclic graph of base classes, where “left-to-right” is the order of appearance of the base classes in the derived class base-specifier-list.
- Then, direct base classes are initialized in declaration order as they appear in the base-specifier-list (regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
- Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition (again regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
- ***Finally,*** the compound-statement of the constructor body is executed.

---

The main reason for using init-lists is to help the compiler with optimisation. Init-lists for non-basic types (i.e., class objects rather than `int`, `float`, etc.) can generally be constructed in-place.

If you create the object then assign to it in the constructor, this generally results in the creation and destruction of temporary objects, which is inefficient.

Init-lists can avoid this (if the compiler is up to it, of course but most of them should be).

The following complete program will output 7 but this is for a specific compiler (CygWin g++) so it doesn't guarantee that behaviour any more than the sample in the original question.

However, as per the citation in the first paragraph above, the standard *does* actually guarantee it.

```
#include <iostream>
class Foo {
    int x;
    public:
        Foo(): x(7) {
            std::cout << x << std::endl;
        }
};
int main (void) {
    Foo foo;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Makes me wonder why people just don't try to compile the source first though :)

Comment: @arul: @dehmann may only have the one compiler. If that behavior is of implementation-defined, compiling won't help. You'd need to refer to the standard.

Comment: Yes, just compiling and trying out doesn't tell you if that will work the same everywhere.

Comment: One reason why I asked the question was that I seem to remember that in the constructor I should refer to the constructor arguments, but not the member vars that just have been initialized, as in:  Foo(std::string str) : str_(str) { // now refer to str rather than str_}. But it seems that's wrong.

Comment: Your long version leaves me confused. With the "output 7" example you give an example similar to the one I had given, and you say it will output 7, but only for specific compilers, and it's not guaranteed?

Comment: I always use the smallest full program for testing and I didn't say it wasn't guaranteed, just that I only tested it on one compiler. You'll need to look into the latest standard that I linked to, to confirm that it specifies that behavior - I believe the original did.

Comment: I don't agree on optimizations being the main reason for initialization lists, but rather construction of bases and members that cannot be default constructed (whose types require parameters to the constructor). It is a too complex discussion to handle just in the comments section. Won't up/downvote

Comment: Well, they can be optimized better since they can be done in-place at construction time (of the member in the init-list, not the object containing it). Using assignment in the constructor of the containing object, you first create a default member then copy-construct it. So while ...

Comment: ... it may not be the main reason, it is certainly a valid reason. It's certainly the main reason I ever used it. And you could just as easily create non-default-constructor members in the constructor of the containing object rather than the init-list.

Comment: That is only a side effect. The member attributes are initialized (or not, depends on the type) _before_ entering the constructor block. If a member attribute is a POD and does not appear in the initialization list, then no extra work is performed by the compiler. Space is reserved but not ...

Comment: ... initialized, so there is no real performance advantage. Only for types that do provide a default constructor the member attribute is initialized first in the initialization list and then assigned in the block.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, C++ constructs all the members before calling the constructur code.

Answer (score 7):

As already answered, initialization lists get completely executed *before* entering the constructor block. So it is completely safe to use (initialized) members in the constructor body.

You have made a comment in the accepted answer about having to *refer to the constructor arguments, but not the member vars* inside the constructor block. You don't.

It is possible that you mistook the fact that you *should* refer to parameters and not to member attributes *inside* the initialization list. As an example, given a class X that has two members (a_ and b_) of type int, the following constructor may be ill-defined:

```
 X::X( int a ) : a_( a ), b( a_*2 ) {}
```

The possible problem here is that the construction of the elements in the initialization list depends on the order of declaration in the class and not the order in which you type the initialization list. If the class were defined as:

```
class X
{
public:
   X( int a );
private:
   int b_;
   int a_; 
};
```

Then, regardless of how you type the initialization list in, the fact is that b_( a_*2 ) will be executed *before* a_ is initialized since the declaration of the members is first b_ and later a_. That will create a bug as your code believes (and probably depends) on b_ being twice the value of a_, and in fact b_ contains garbage. The simplest solution is not refering to the members:

```
 X::X( int a ) : a_( a ), b( a*2 ) {} // correct regardless of how X is declared
```

Avoiding this pitfall is the reason why you are suggested not to use member attributes as part of the initialization of other members.