# If init lists always be processed to constructor body, but it appears else in my code

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization-list

So, I've read this:
[Will the initialization list always be processed before the constructor code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723973/will-the-initialization-list-always-be-processed-before-the-constructor-code)

and given the following constructor:

```
public:
    A (int x=5):x(x+1)
    {
        cout << "In A::A x= " << x << endl;
    }
```

and the sample of code in the main:

```
A a1(10);
```

I don't understand the result:
"In A::A x = 10"
when according to my logic it should be:
"In A::A x = 11"

But instead, x = 11 only after the constructor body invoked. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" with this code is that both the parameter to the constructor and the member variable are named `x`. That is, `x` might not refer to the `x` you expect.

In this case, `x` refers to the parameter of the constructor - and that has a value of 10. The reason is that when C++ encounters a scope where there are two variables with the same identifier, then the most local scope wins. Here: the `x` from the parameter value. If you want to use the memver variable, change the code to use `this.x` instead of just `x`:

```
A (int x=5):x(x+1)
{
    cout << "In A::A x= " << this->x << endl;
}
```

Now the value you see should be 11, not 10. `this` is a pointer to the current object, so `this->x` is the value of the member variable `x` of the current object.

Of course, it would be still better to use different names. That way you can avoid such confusion.

Comment: `this` is a pointer to current object so is should be `this->x` not `this.x`

Comment: Thank you for spotting the mistake. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

`x` in the body of your constructor means the argument `x`.

The first `x` in `x(x+1)` is the member field of your `class A`. That is the source of the confusion.

You should give another name to your member field. Some conventions start them with a `_` or a `m_`.

```
class A {
private:
    int m_x;
public:
    A (int x=5):m_x(x+1)
    {
        cout << "In A::A x= " << m_x << endl;
    }
};
```

In your case with `A a(10);`, your constructor will write `11`.